# String representation of Python modules

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

In Python a module imported has a string representation of the form
`<module <module-name> from <module-path>>`.

As an example, after `import numpy`, `print(numpy)` returns

`<module 'numpy' from 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\python3.9\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>`

When dealing with classes one can modify this behaviour through the methods `__str__` and `__repr__`. Is there a way to do the same with modules?

In particular I would like to write a module `my_module` such that

```py
import my_module as md
print(md)
```

returns and ad hoc string.

I tried to define a `__str__` and `__repr__` functions in the module's `__init__.py` file assuming print would call these functions to provide a string representation of the module, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Methods like `__str__()` are looked up in the *class*, not the instance.  And the class that defines modules is an internal type, implemented in C; there's no mechanism for changing its methods from Python code.

Comment: Actually I can monkey-patch `__str__` and `__repr__` into modules, for example `re.__str__ = lambda: 'A fish'` and if I then call `re.__str__()` we get the fish. But if I call `str(re)` we get the "default" function. Might be hardwired on the CPython side.